# Access specific sections of link

Tags: links, href

I want to access this site say, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket#History

Now I want the specific section 'History' to be shown as soon as I open the link

In overleaf I did this, \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket#History}{link}
But it gives me this error -> llegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa, and when I open the link after compiling even if it get an error I get this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket##History, 2 '#' and is wrong

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106514/47927 ? If this does not answer your question, please consider providing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), so it becomes clear what packages you use etc.

Comment: To expand a bit on thie above comment: Normally, if you use the `\url` command that is used by the `\href` command internally, you should be able to use `#` for the URL just like this. There might be a situation where this does not work, but then you should be able to use `\#` instead of `#` (which still will become `#` in the link in the final document).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [hash-tag in `\href` causes error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44738/5764)

Comment: You seem to have some conflict with packages

Answer (score 0):

The `\#` escapes the hash symbol, ensuring that LaTeX interprets it as part of the URL rather than as a special character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is an example of how to link to a specific section in a Wikipedia article.
Click on the following link to go to the 'History' section of the cricket page on Wikipedia:
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket\#History}{Cricket History}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works just as well without escaping #

Comment: There might be some conflict between packages in the question

Comment: That's why it is better to wait until a question is clear enough before answering.